# Overwriting XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send breaks after navigating via breadcrumbs menu

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

We're working with a custom frontend framework that's based on PrimeFaces/JSF.

Lately, we added a display that shows how long until the user gets logged out due to inactivity. To correctly reset the countdown on user activity, I've overwritten the `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send` method via JavaScript:

```
var minutesUntilTimeout = 60;
var logoutAt = minutesUntilTimeout * 60 * 1000 + new Date().getTime();

var send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
    send.call(this, data);
    logoutAt = minutesUntilTimeout * 60 * 1000 + new Date().getTime();
}
```

This works correctly as it is.

However, we encountered a problem:
The JS code gets executed on page load, and to work correctly, it is mandatory that `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send` contains the original functionality. However, sometimes it still contains our overwritten function from the last JS execution (e.g. when we get to a page via the breadcrumb menu). This breaks the application, since every user action that uses `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send` will trigger the overwritten function, that internally calls the `var send` "original" function, which is the same function in this special case, creating an infinite loop. I think it has to do with the HTTP request, since as far as I remember, the breadcrumbs use GET and all buttons, main menu etc. use POST (but this is just a guess, I'm not that deep into the implementation details of our framework).

Is there any way to ensure that `XMLHttpRequest.prototype` correctly resets on ALL page changes, aside from simply avoiding the breadcrumbs?

Comment: Is `var send` a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

Once again, the rubber duck principle holds true - minutes after posting, I found a workaround. In case anyone ever needs it, I added a case differentiation:

```
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldSend !== "function") {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldSend.call(this, data);
        logoutAt = minutesUntilTimeout * 60 * 1000 + new Date().getTime();
    }
}
```